# How do I parse text/plain code in Java?

Tags: android, text-parsing

I am having a real problem with parsing and I dont know how to deal with it. Im working on a database that has a very untypical return of information . When you make a request the response is in plain text and I have no idea how to parse it.

The result of a query looks like this:

```
error=0; 
---
name= Pen
detailname= TextMarker Highlighter Pink
---
```

There is no html, XML or json involved - The result litterally comes back like this.

I have no idea on how to parse plain text in Java. How do I parse for example, so I only get the information following name= or any other of the categories? I have tried using JSoup, but I cant figure it out. Could anyone with experience shed some light on how I can filter this?

Thank you 
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like a *.properties-file I would suggest

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(inputStream);
```

You just have to get your results as an InputStream or Reader (i.e. StringReader) and can then access it like Properties.

```
String error = p.getProperty("error");
String name = p.getProperty("name");
String detailName = p.getProperty("detailname");
```

which will get you:

```
error: "0;"
name: " Pen"
detailName: " TextMarker Highlighter Pink"
```

The only thing you have to keep in mind is that "---" will be an entry in the properties as well.

Newlines in the values may break this.

Comment: I owe you a beer! Thank you a million times!! This seems to have done the trick, but I have to check when I get home to!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works on Android but in Java, can't you use a `Scanner` to read in the text?
e.g. something along the lines of

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fFile));
while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )
{
     String content = scanner.next();
     ....

     // check text for whatever values you need, e.g.
     if(content.startsWith("name=")
     {
            // do your thing
            ....
     }
}
```